# Issue with starting dialog from receiver on one condition

Tags: android, android-activity, dialog

I want to show a dialog from receiver. So, I started an activity with transparent background and displays a dialog. Below is my class.

```
public class DialogDisplayingActivity extends Activity{

  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
 {
    super.onCreate(....);
    showDialog();
 }
 private void showDialog()
    {

    final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(this);

    dialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    // Include dialog.xml file
    dialog.setContentView(R.layout.dialoglayout);
    // Set dialog title
    .........................
    ............................

    dialog.show();
}
}
```

In my receiver class, I start the activity as shown below:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, SendingPermissionActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("details", value);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

The issue is --> suppose if the first dialog is shown at 8.45am and user doesn't dismiss it and if the receiver receives another command to show the dialog at 8.46 am, it doesn't show up. The control is not coming to `DialogDisplayingActivity` at all. But I want to display dialogs as many times as the receiver receives i.e., I need to start activities that many times. Can someone suggests me to achieve this?

**Manifest.xml:**

```
<activity
               android:name="com.example.note.DialogDisplayingActivity"
               android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Translucent.NoTitleBar"
               android:taskAffinity=""
               android:excludeFromRecents="true">
        </activity>
```

Comment: @rick make the dialog variable global, add two functions show and hide to show and cancel the dialog, now for each new request to show something in dialog first call hide, then call show ! i hope you got it !

Comment: Are you sure the `Receiver` class is getting called again? If not then please also post how you are calling it

Comment: @codeMagic twntee, arman I am really sure, the control flows to receiver even second time, because I can see with log statements. Everything is normal, but the activity is not getting started again if the activity is already there. If it is dismissed I am finishing my activity and the future dialogs are shown as usual, but when the current is not dismissed, the dialogs in the particular period are not shown. is there anything that I need to put in manifest in the activity tag to start the same activity multiple times?

Comment: No, don't need a special attribute in `manifest`. Maybe post your whole receiver class as suggested by Arman